# datapump_exp_full_database role is missing

Tags: oracle, centos6

I'm new to oracle. I want to try exporting and importing database. In order to do that I need both datapump_exp_full_database and datapump_imp_full_database. When I tried to grant both of these roles to a user, it always says role is missing. So when I tried to check the datapump role on the Oracle Enterprise Manager to be sure, both of the roles aren't there. What did I do wrong here guys? I already logged in as SYS when I tried to grant there roles. Please bear with me because i'm really new in this. Thanks in advance

I'm using Oracle 10g on CentOS 6 32-Bit
Here is the screenshot of the roles I took from Enterprise Manager:

[Screenshot of the roles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0IUg.png)

Updated :
I tried exporting with a newly created user, which I had granted both the EXP_FULL_DATABASE and IMP_FULL_DATABASE. But still couldn't do it. It kept failed exporting.

I already created the dpump_dir directory. Granted the user to WRITE and READ on dpump_dir
Here's the command I ran with its result :

```
[oracle@localhost db_1]$ expdp XYZ/****@testdb01 directory=dpump_dir dumpfile=db_dumpfile.dmp logfile=expdp_dbdump.log FULL=YES;
```

Export: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Thursday, 09 August, 2018 2:39:41

Copyright (c) 2003, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 10g Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
ORA-39002: invalid operation

ORA-39070: Unable to open the log file.

ORA-29283: invalid file operation

ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 475

ORA-29283: invalid file operation

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're using such an ancient Oracle version?

Comment: Does the directory `dpump_dir` in Oracle exist and point to an existing directory? Does the OS user oracle have the necessary privileges on the OS directory?

Comment: I have to use this version because I have no other choice due to circumstances

Comment: "Unable to open the log file" sounds as if you didn't grant WRITE privilege on it to user XYZ. Did you? As SYS, you'd `grant read, write on directory dpump_dir to xyz`.

Comment: I already did grant the user with both WRITE and READ on the directory dpump_dir

Answer (score -1):

I believe you're mistaken. Roles are named `EXP_FULL_DATABASE` and `IMP_FULL_DATABASE` (without the "datapump_" prefix).

If they don't exist, these roles are created by running the `CATEXP.SQL` (you should be able to locate the file on the disk).

More info on [Administering user Privileges](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/network.101/b10773/admusers.htm).

Comment: Is that so? I'm trying to export a database, I already grant both the EXP_FULL_DATABASE and IMP_FULL_DATABASE to my newly created user. I already made the DIRECTORY needed for the export. But still no luck. I already tried exporting as SYS too

Comment: The OP is correct - the roles really have the `DATAPUMP` prefix (see https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-8B6975D3-3BEC-4584-B416-280125EEC57E.htm#SUTIL807). However, the OP is using Oracle 10g - these roles might have been introduced in a later version.

Comment: @Frank, that's why my link points to 10g documentation which shows that those roles don't have the DATAPUMP prefix.

Comment: @Littlefoot You're right - I didn't check your documentation link, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Although the [Oracle documentation for version 12](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-8B6975D3-3BEC-4584-B416-280125EEC57E.htm#SUTIL807) indeed mentions the `DATAPUMP_` roles, the [documentation for version 10](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_overview.htm#i1009203) (which you're using) only mentions `EXP_FULL_DATABASE`. So your installation probably is fine (just very, very outdated).

The error message `ORA-39070: Unable to open the log file.` seems to indicate a problem on file system level.

You should check

- whether the directory dpump_dir in Oracle exists and points to an existing directory: 
  `SELECT * FROM ALL_DIRECTORIES`
- whether the OS user oracle has the necessary privileges on this directory

Also, you might want to look at the [Oracle Base article on data pump in 10g](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g); it contains a step-by-step instruction for a full database export that includes all the necessary steps.

Comment: I already created the dpump_dir, I made sure it was there by using select from all_directories. I also have granted to write and read the directory to the user(XYZ)